# add list of tables and columns from database to database

Tags: oracle

I have 2 different database : db1@srvr1  and db2@srvr2 .
I have a list of 80 tables and 100 columns that exists in db1@srvr1 and not exists (missing) in db2@srvr2.
I want to add those missing tables and columns to db2. how to that in a quick way ? 
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE','TMP') this query will only give me DLL of one table.

Comment: by "add" - do you mean create  tables with no data, or copy the tables, data and all

Comment: @jimmcnamara create only the table (DDL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the tables from your schema:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ( 'TABLE', table_name ) from user_tables;
```

You will have to "treat" the output to make it usable (assuming sqlplus, set long, lines, pages, head, and maybe look at the dbma_metadata set_transformation flags ).

Comment: as I mentioned in my question this query will give me only one table @teng

Comment: @Moudiz - no, it will give you the ddl for all tables in your schema. If you log in as SCOTT/tiger and run it you get the SCOTT schema tables EMP, DEPT, etc. The query reads "user_tables" and passes each table_name to teh get_dll call.

If you are only seeing one table, it's because you only have one table in teh schema. If you are connecting as UserA but want to run this on tables owned by UserB you would need to query "all_tables" and add "WHERE OWNER = 'USERB'", and also add the owner to the get_ddl call.